# Web server startup failed: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, centos7

CentOS 7

Docker 20.10.5

java version "1.8.0_162"

PostgreSQL 9.6.2

I try to start SonarQube 7.6.9 in Docker like this:

```
  sudo docker run --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/sonar sonarqube:7.6.9
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.PlatformImpl] Web server startup failed: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
```

P.S.
If I start without connect to PostgreSQL then SonarQube 7.6.9 is success run

```
  sudo docker run --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:7.6.9
```

Comment: Postgres has no LTS designations so this error is not coming from it.  SonarQube does, so I would verify what version you are actually running.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I change  my post, but same error

Comment: " SonarQube does, so I would verify what version you are actually running." still applies. Pretty sure the issue is with SonarQube, you need to check from that end.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You was right. After read this migration help https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrading/, now I success run SonarQube 7.6.9 in Docker

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error when trying to upgrade from *Sonar 6.7.5* to *Sonar 8.9.2*

Searching in the web i found that this happens because ***migration route is needed*** between versions.

In my case it was not possible to jump directly from version 6.7.5 to version 8.9.2. First I had to jump to version 7.9.6 and then to version 8.9.2 (
you can read more about Migration path in: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/before-you-upgrade/).

I hope this can serve you.